# How to lock and access 25 records at a time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a console application which will be running in 3 pc. I want console application 2 & 3 will not be able to access those records which have been selected by console application1.

I found a sample code that shown some way to access table as a queue. in the below SQL working 1 data at a time but my requirement is to work with 25 data. So guide me what to change in below SQL?

I rarely work with sql server. i found code which close to my requirement but what i need to change there to get it work not very sure. so looking for suggestion.

Please see this code

```
DECLARE @NextID INTEGER

BEGIN TRANSACTION

-- Find the next queued item that is waiting to be processed
SELECT TOP 1 @NextID = ID
FROM MyQueueTable WITH (UPDLOCK, READPAST)
WHERE StateField = 0
ORDER BY ID ASC

-- if we've found one, mark it as being processed
IF @NextId IS NOT NULL
    UPDATE MyQueueTable SET Status = 1 WHERE ID = @NextId

COMMIT TRANSACTION

-- If we've got an item from the queue, return to whatever is going to process it
IF @NextId IS NOT NULL
    SELECT * FROM MyQueueTable WHERE ID = @NextID
```

1. I need to **process at a time 25 records**. so what I need to change in above code?
2. Why last select is required?

```
IF @NextId IS NOT NULL
    SELECT * FROM MyQueueTable WHERE ID = @NextID
```

My first select will return data then last select is required at all? please tell me purpose of last select.

Comment: What does "not be able to access those records" mean? Can't update them? Can't read them? Can't tell they exist, e.g. can create duplicates of them in spite of constraints? Is there an appropriate [lock hint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-ver15) for the behavior you seek?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can use `UPDATE` with an `OUTPUT` clause to output the data into a temp table in one statement.** This does not require a transaction.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #process;
CREATE TABLE #process (ID INT);

-- Find the next queued item that is waiting to be processed
UPDATE mqt
SET Status = 1
OUTPUT inserted.ID
  INTO #process (ID)
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (25) *
    FROM MyQueueTable WITH (READPAST)
    WHERE StateField = 0
    ORDER BY ID ASC
) AS mqt;
```

Comment: I like this! It still uses an implicit transaction, but condensing it all into a single statement is very nice. Curious: How would you handle an exception on this - just wrap it in `TRY...CATCH`?

Comment: Basically yes, catch it on the outside. Depends exactly what processing you are doing, to be honest

Comment: please tell me why you remove hold lock? if it would be there then any negative impact would occur ?

Comment: You can;t use `HOLDLOCK` and `READPAST` together

Comment: if possible can you please share link which would discuss the reason not to use `HOLDLOCK and READPAST together `. what would be consequence or bad impact if anyone use HOLDLOCK and READPAST together. thanks

Comment: @Mist https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=16589b5310adfed2619712efb999c664

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a scalar variable, you could create a temp table that you `INSERT` the top 25 records into.

```
-- Find the next queued item that is waiting to be processed
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #process;
CREATE TABLE #process (ID INT);
INSERT INTO #process
SELECT TOP (25) ID
  FROM MyQueueTable WITH (UPDLOCK, READPAST)
 WHERE StateField = 0
 ORDER BY ID ASC;

-- if we've found one, mark it as being processed
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP (1) ID FROM #process)
   BEGIN
    UPDATE MyQueueTable
       SET Status = 1 
      FROM MyQueueTable AS mqt 
      JOIN #process AS p
        ON mqt.ID = p.ID;
   END;
```

And a couple of tips on coding practice, if I may:

- be sure to end your statements with semicolons (;) to separate them and improve readability (also it will one day be a requirement)
- avoid using `SELECT *` in deployed code. Instead, specify the columns you want to  `SELECT`